# Access to undeclared static property error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm a Laravel and PHP newbie. I'm trying to modify some code in a buggy package I'm using called Confide based on commits on github. I get an error message in Confide.php saying:

```
Access to undeclared static property: Zizaco\Confide\Confide::$rules
```

From my research, it appears that the 'static' is replaced by 'Zizaco\Confide\Confide' in the source code. How can I make it reference the correct code? The relevant code is shown below:

```
public function resetPassword( $params )
{
    //$password = array_get($params, 'password', '');
    $this->password = array_get($params, 'password', '');
    $this->password_confirmation = array_get($params, 'password_confirmation', '');

    $passwordValidators = array(
        'password' => static::$rules['password'],
        'password_confirmation' => static::$rules['password_confirmation'],
    );
```

Comment: Is this `resetPassword` function in your model? Is the `$rules` a static property in your model? If yes to both, use `self` instead of `static`. Because the function is an instance method, if `$rules` is non-static, you should use `$this` instead.